# The letter ف is wrong for only executable jar

Tags: java, utf-8

Locally (netbeans) all works well.

1. In netbeans encoding is UTF-8
2. In Mysql is utf8_general_ci
3. Connection is like this:

   ```
   String Unicode  = "useUnicode = true & CharacterEncoding = UTF-8 & charSet = UTF-8?";
   con = DriverManager.getConnection (urlBaseDonnees + unicode, "root", "");
   ```
4. Read the SQL script I add:

   ```
   s = new Scanner (new FileReader ("2sga_local.sql"));  
   // ... 
   while (s.hasNext ()) {  
     String req = new String (line.getBytes (), "UTF-8");  
     // ...
     statementBDD.executeUpdate (req);  
   }
   ```

As I generated the executable jar all Arabic letters in the database are ok except the letter **ف**, and **f** is the letter to which does not know Arabic.

Comment: This looks like a bug report, not a question. If it's a bug report, it's a pretty good one, but on the wrong site. If it's a question, there should be a '?' character somewhere.

Comment: Try using `InputStreamReader` and explicitly specify `UTF-8`.

Comment: sorry this is my first question and I think it's a **bug** I did **not** find solution and InputStreamReader gives same result

Comment: Why do you use `new String(line.getBytes (), "UTF-8")`, why not read the file using UTF-8 to begin with? Multiple character set conversions are bound to produce problems.

Comment: I finally find the solution using the class you can find on this link:
[link](https://github.com/BenoitDuffez/ScriptRunner).you can use it as follows:            **Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/2sga_local"+unicode, "root", "");
ScriptRunner runner = new ScriptRunner(connection, false, false);
File fileDir = new File("2sga_local.sql");
   
  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
     new InputStreamReader(
                      new FileInputStream(fileDir), "UTF8"));
                runner.runScript(in);**thank you for all

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution using the `ScriptRunner` class you can find on this link: **https://github.com/BenoitDuffez/ScriptRunner**.

You can use it as follows:

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/2sga_local" + unicode, "root", "");
ScriptRunner runner = new ScriptRunner(connection, false, false);
File fileDir = new File("2sga_local.sql");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileDir), "UTF8"));
runner.runScript(in);
```